# Is there a more efficient way to express this query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a query for my mysql database but I just want to know if there is more of a simpler way of achieving something, here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT value 
  FROM drivers 
  WHERE drivers_id = '$driver1' OR drivers_id =  '$driver2' OR drivers_id = '$driver3'"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 1; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  ${'value'.$i} = $row['value']; 
  $i++; 
}
```

This is how I want my code as it is shorter, but the problem I am having is that I need to know that where the $driver1 variable is found in the database the data retrieved for that is placed inside the value1 variable, and the retrieved information for $driver2 is placed inside $value2. However it grabs the data from the database in the order that it comes across the matches. I don't want to have to write 3 different queries for this because I am sure it can be done in one.

Comment: It sounds like you need your matches to be ordered in a certain way.  What's the condition that sets the order?

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you could use `SELECT value FROM drivers WHERE drivers_id IN ($driver1, $driver2, $driver3)` instead of all the `OR`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql="SELECT drivers_id, value FROM drivers WHERE drivers_id IN ('$driver1','$driver2','$driver3')"; 

$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  ${'value_for_'.$row['drivers_id']}=$row['value']; 
}
```

Boom.

Though personally, instead of on-the-fly variables, I'd use an array w/ the id's as keys:

```
...
$resultArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  $resultArray[$row['drivers_id']]=$row['value']; 
}
```

Comment: actually this does not work for me :(, its still not retrieving the data in the order that is specified in the IN clause. It is still retrieving and placing in variables depending on who it matches first. It needs to be in the order of the IN clause because I am returning the variables too the webpage in that order.

Comment: The order it returns should be irrelevant (if your code is designed well); the `while` loop creates dynamic variable names that include the values of `$driver(1|2|3)`. Perhaps you should post your original code that references the original `$value(1|2|3)` variables? Also, you could add `order by drivers_id` to the end of the SQL (assuming that the values of `$driver(1|2|3)` are ascending).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the order of the results, you can add an `order by` clause to the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT drivers_id, value FROM drivers WHERE drivers_id IN ('$driver1','$driver2','$driver3') ORDER BY drivers_id";
...
```